# Symfony2: missing profiling information

Tags: performance, symfony, kernel, profiling

I try to improve performances of my Symfony2 application. In the profiler, there is something strange: between the kernel.request et kernel.controller, there is a hole with nothing:

[image: profiling]

What event is between ? How to know it ?